# Nested JavaFX ExecutorService shutdown

Tags: java, executorservice, shutdown, java-threads

For example, if you have an ExecutorServic(ES) in JavaFX that starts a task, which in turn contains another ES and starts new tasks. - What will happen to  2nd ES's threads when the 1st ES is shut down. I assume they would not be shut down (as they are not if only main thread is shut down, if I understand correctly).

Answer (score 0):

When you establish an executor service backed by a thread pool, it is vital that you shutdown that service and its threadpool. If your app exits, your task and the pool may continue onward, as a sort of zombie. Be sure the hooks into the lifecycle of your app (launching, quitting, and such) is being properly used to start and stop your executors and their thread pools.

Also, you can reuse an executor service and its thread pool rather than spawning a new one. There are times where it makes sense to have a separate pool, but you should be very clear about your motivation in doing so.

When you do establish two or more executor service, they and their backing thread pools are separate. **Shutting down one has no effect on the other.**

By the way, it can be sensible in some cases to have a task in a scheduled executor service schedule yet another task. But it could also be a “code smell”, a clue about a poor design. You’ve not given enough detail to tell which is the case here, but I suggest you think about it and search the many other existing posts on executors.